# Universally synchronizing a block of code [Without ObjectLocking]

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a simple code I came up with to illustrate my question:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sleepTime = 10, N = 1000;
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

                { //BLOCK 1
                    //I want these two instructions to run one right after the other one
                    System.out.println("Thread one rules!!");
                    System.out.println("Im in 1!!!\n");
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime); //I also tried yield
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

                { //BLOCK 2
                    //I want these two instructions to run one right after the other one
                    System.out.println("Thread two rules!!");
                    System.out.println("Im in 2!!!\n");
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime); //I also tried yield
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have each block called "atomically"? meaning "Thread one rules!!" will ALWAYS come right before "Im in 1!!!"

[Output example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VahVG.png)

**I don't want to use any dummy objects in a synchronized block, nor any wait/notify statements.** I would like an implementation that works with hundreds of threads running together. I tried with synchronized statements that take a common object as argument, mySocketServer, but it started giving me timing issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "dummy object" do you mean a `final Object lock = new Object()` that all threads share? That would be the common approach. Even with hundreds of threads, if you want to establish a lock that all threads obey, then there's inherently no way around all of them using that same lock, right? Also, unless your CPU has hundreds of cores, there's not much benefit in having hundreds of threads unless they each spend a lot of time waiting for resources (like a URL response that takes a while). And if that's the case, then them locking on the same object won't matter, anyway.

Comment: The capabilities of the hardware on which you run your program are finite.  Hundreds of threads running simultaneously are likely to stress even fairly beefy hardware, and yes, forcing them to serialize their accesses to a single resource is likely to speed the onset of performance problems.  Possibly you need more hardware.  Possibly you need pervasive design improvements.  But the kind of "atomicity" you require can be achieved *only* by one variety of locking or another.

Comment: Do you care *specifically* about output to stdout (or some other I/O stream)? In that case, none of the normal `java.io.` classes ever gurantee atomicity, as they can block (and suspend the thread) at any time. In fact, I'm not aware of any operating system where this is possible in the general case, and special cases are usually OS-specific.

Comment: You have two blocks of code, executed by two different threads, and you want to ensure that only one thread is inside the "critical" block of code at a time. That means that if the other thread want to enter the critical block, it has to **wait** until the first thread exits its critical block. Such a wait state is best accomplished by obtaining a **lock**. Any other mechanism will have the same effect, i.e. second thread waits, so why do you think *locking* is causing excessive performance issue here? It's the *wait* that reduces performance, not the *lock*. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: A lock is the most efficient way to make a thread wait, because it actually halts the thread, allowing the CPU to do other things. If threads have to wait on an event, locking is by far the most efficient way to do it. Locking is the correct tool for the problem you specified, so why are you looking for another solution? Doesn't matter whether the lock is done using `synchronized`, a `ReadWriteLock`, a `Semaphore`, or any of the other concurrent tools made available, a lock is a lock is a lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most relevant way to do that is to use a single call:

```
System.out.println("<first line>\n<second line>");
```

By the way, I believe timing should not be affected by additional synchronisation blocks. At any case, you can use System.out

```
synchronized(System.out) {
...
}
```

And this definitely should not affect timing. PrintStream methods like println() already include such synchronisation, as result this additional synchronized block will rather optimise locking.

Answer (score 2):

No , you have to lock around the System.out to prevent 
Thread one rules!!
Thread two rules!!

even locking each block will allow two threads to write to System.out at the same time

Answer (score 2):

You need to lock an object one way ore another. The standard practice is to have a shared accessible object like `public Object sharedLock = new Object()` and useit in your `syncrhonized` block.